# AngularJS. Can't change element in directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

AngularJS 1.5.0. I'm using custom directive `ddTextCollapse` to collapse\expand long posts in thread and recently encountered strange problem - some posts won't expand due to DOM not being changed by script.
Here's code:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.doc.collapsed = false;
  var child = element.children();

  scope.doc.toggle = function() {
    scope.doc.collapsed = !scope.doc.collapsed;
    child.toggleClass('collapsed');
    console.dir(child); //everything is fine! Should have changed DOM also, but alas.
  };

  attrs.$observe('ddTextCollapseMaxHeight', function() {
    var maxHeight = scope.$eval(attrs.ddTextCollapseMaxHeight);

    if (child.height() > maxHeight) {
      child.addClass('collapsed');
      scope.doc.collapsed = true;
      var toggleButton = $compile('<i class="material-icons collapse-text-toggle" ng-click="doc.toggle()">more_horiz</i>')(scope);
      child.after(toggleButton);
    }

  });
}
```

I'm really confused about why that can happen. It seems to depend on the type of post but the problem occurs even when the markup is identical. The markup:

```
<div ng-if="discus.expanded[doc.unid] !== 'attached'" dd-text-collapse dd-text-collapse-max-height="100" class="col-lg-24 martop5 text-content">
  <div ng-bind-html="doc.body | linkCreate | nl2br | quoteAuthor | trustAsHtml" class=""></div>
</div>
```

It looks like when you messed up with scopes and change child only when you really need to change the parent. But again, I can't see why or how that can happen.

Comment: Do you mind adding a plunkr for this? Also, I feel $scope.apply() after your collapse or expand might help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can download the angular js custom directive for this task.
There are many directives but I have used the below and it works fine.

http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-readmore

Comment: I need to work with html markup in the posts, this directive can work only with plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using jQuery selector (instead of `element` or `child`) and working with it for it was obviously some Angular bug.